# ERROR with "SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found"

Tags: c++, xcode, error-handling, game-development, sfml

I ran into an error in X Code for the library when every I was using the #include SFML/Graphics.hpp however it said the file was not found [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZND4.png)

I even imported the libraries for the SFML and the Header search Paths [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLzWj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDVEZ.png)

Comment: I expect you typed the wrong path in the "Header Search Paths". Make sure that whatever folder you typed there when you append `/SFML/Graphics.hpp` to the folder you typed this is an existing file.

Comment: @drescherjm it still doesnt work when i put /SFML/Graphics.hpp

Comment: @AXB2028 Nobody asked you to type `/SFML/Graphics.hpp` that would be wrong. The reason this does not work is that you put the wrong thing in the header search paths. However the image that you posted does not show the full header search path you typed. Please edit the question with the full header search path as **text** not as an image. Then we should be able to get this sorted out.